# Email error: "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key"

Tags: app-store, cocoapods, ios10, appstore-approval, info.plist

I have an issue that I haven't been able to resolve when submitting my app to **App Store**.  The deployment target of the app is iOS 10.0

I get this error with many third-party libraries, I use CocoaPods to manage the libraries and the report of the errors is sent via email, right after doing the upload to App Store:

> Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at
>   '/Payload/APP_NAME.app/Target Support Files/FRAMEWORK_FOLDER/Info.plist' does not contain a
>   bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain
>   an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its
>   Info.plist and using a      CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this
>   bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the
>   developer of the framework for an update to address this issue

So I tried removing the CFBundleExecutable key and using BNDL in the CFBundlePackageType key, as the error indicates and also because is what I have found in many forums. But by doing this, I can't run the app with Xcode, the build is successful, but before opening it prompts this message:

> Bundle at path
>   /PATH/Payload/NAME.app/Frameworks/FRAMEWORK_NAME.framework has missing
>   or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist

And the app doesn't run.

Therefore, if I try resolving the error, the app stops working with Xcode. I haven't found a different solution and I need to upload my app to App Store, btw, is the first time I'm uploading it.
I have tried also looking if is something related to CocoaPods, but haven't found anything. Also, I tried setting the `Enable bitcode : NO`, but didn't work either):

Any thoughts?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Make sure that neither your **target's Info.plist file** nor any of the **folder or files generated by CocoaPods** are added in the "Copy Bundle Resources" in the "Build Phases" of your target app.

In my case the "Target Support Files" folder was added, therefore all the Info.plist files of the libraries. Removing it solved the issue and I can submit the app at last!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on Git , This solved my problem. Just submited my app and finished processing, Hope this helps someone.

Found the solution:

The "Target Support Files" folder generated by CocoaPods was added to the "Copy Bundle Resources" in the "Build Phases" of the app, therefore all the Info.plist files of the libraries. Removing it solved the issue and I can submit the app at last!